# Indicating kmodule.xml to drools

Tags: java, xml, jar, drools, stateless

I am developing an application using Drools 6.1.0. I create a stateless session:

```
KieServices kieServices = KieServices.Factory.get();
KieContainer kContainer = kieServices.getKieClasspathContainer();
kSession = kContainer.newStatelessKieSession();
```

Also I got a default kmodule.xml:

`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<kmodule xmlns="http://jboss.org/kie/6.0.0/kmodule">
</kmodule>`

It could be found at META-INF/kmodule.xml

When I run the application on Eclipse it works perfectly. I am trying to pack the app in a runnable jar file. However when I run the jar file the kmodule.xml can't be found.

How can I indicate to my application wheres is the kmodule.xml file? Is there any other alternative than using the classpath?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Are you using a maven structure? the kmodule.xml file needs to be inside the src/main/resources/META-INF/  directory as far as I remember.

Comment: You remember correctly. :) I can also confirm that this does work in an executable jar/uber-jar.

Comment: Yes it is. Exporting the project with maven plugins works perfectly. I followed the instructions from http://crunchify.com/how-to-create-build-java-project-including-all-dependencies-using-maven-maven-resources-maven-dependency-maven-jar-plugin-tutorial/

Thank you!